# Можно ли убрать title у картинки с помощью стилей?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть картинка, которая добавляется с помощью конструктора на сайт и  ее по умолчанию присваивается  title.

```
<img src="http://support.eye.fi/wp-content/uploads/2007/09/arrow-down.png.pagespeed.ce.sb6_oS5SGc.png" title="pagespeed">
```

Можно ли не затрагивая html с помощью стилей убрать title у картинки? Или без скрипта никак?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, что без вмешательства скрипта, Вашу задачу будет не решить. (Хотя на Вашем месте я бы всё-же правил именно html). Но, раз требуется именно так, то:

javascript:

```
var title = document.querySelectorAll('img[title]'); 
var allTitle = title.length;
for (i=0; i<allTitle; i++){
    title[i].removeAttribute('title');
}
```

jquery:

```
$("img").removeAttr("title");
```

Comment: да, жаль, что не решить - спасибо! а не правлю html, т.к. мне нужно отменить title только на 2ух картинках, а на всех остальных оставить

Comment: А как дополнить js, если требуется скрыть тайтлы только у картинок с определённым классом? Например, имя этого класса "photo". При этом тайтлы у картинок, не имеющих классов, должны отображаться в стандартном режиме. Извиняюсь за свой вопрос, просто в js я полный ноль.

Comment: @Иван В `querySelectorAll`, вместо `'img[title]'` выбирать по классу нужному: `'.photo'`

Comment: Спасибо за кусочек кода JS для скрывания названий картинок, на Wordpress чудесно работает.

Answer (score 4):

Если и кликать по этим картинкам не нужно, то можно обойтись `pointer-events:none;`

```css
img.no-tilte {
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
нет тултипа:<br>
<img class="no-tilte" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTw8O.jpg?s=48&g=1" title=""Stranger in the Q"><br>
есть тултип:<br>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTw8O.jpg?s=48&g=1" title="Stranger in the Q">
```